# Display json array in grid in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am facing issue while displaying JSON array data which i am getting from service into html
Below is my `component.ts` file code from which i am getting jSON data

```
userdata(){
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res)=>{
this.arrBirds = res.json() as Application[];

console.log(this.arrBirds)
});
```

Below is my HTML code in which i want to display JSON data in a grid

```
<table cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="search_grid_view table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th style="min-width: 100px;">Login Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Agreement Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>User Type</th>
            <th>Email</th> -->
            <!-- <th>Action</th> -->


            <th *ngFor="let col of getColumns">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let char of Griddata">
            <td *ngFor="let col of getColumns">
              {{char[col]}
            </td>
            <!-- <td>Demo</td>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>ISDA, MRA</td>
            <td><a class="red_green_btn red_button" href="javascript:void(0);">In-Active</a></td>
            <td>eClerx</td>
            <td>demo.user@eclerx.com</td> -->
            <!-- <td><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/images/edit.png" alt="" /> </a></td> -->
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

But the grid is not getting populated with the JSON data.
What should be the approach for above problem?

Comment: what is in Griddata? Can you show code how you are assigning Griddata?

Comment: what is output of `console.log(this.arrBirds)`?

Comment: its a JSON data which i am sending from service

Comment: the data is not visible in html? but it is console ?

Comment: `*ngFor="let char of Griddata"`, but your variable is `arrBirds`.

Comment: yes..i was triying something else. i am passing arrbirds only to HTML

Comment: i am also passing grid headers grom my component as below
    this.getColumns = ["intUserId","vcrFirstName"]

Comment: when passing arrbirds it throws below error
    Cannot find a differ supporting object